# Not able to output application logs to file on JBOSS EAP 6.4 XPASS image using periodic-rotating-file-handler

Tags: logging, openshift, jboss6.x

I'm using JBOSS 6.4 EAP  on openshift v3. I'm able to view application logs on console but not able to output them to file. I'm trying to use the  periodic-rotating-file-handler. Below is my standalone-openshift.xml config:

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="OPENSHIFT"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>                
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>            
        <async-handler name="ASYNC">
            <queue-length value="512"/>
            <overflow-action value="block"/>
            <subhandlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </subhandlers>
        </async-handler>
        <async-handler name="FILEASYNC">
            <queue-length value="512"/>
            <overflow-action value="block"/>
            <subhandlers>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </subhandlers>
        </async-handler>            
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="ASYNC"/>
                <handler name="FILEASYNC"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>            
        <formatter name="OPENSHIFT">
            <custom-formatter module="org.jboss.logmanager.ext" class="org.jboss.logmanager.ext.formatters.LogstashFormatter"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue and know what I'm doing incorrectly? I'm able to see the server startup logs but no application logs on the file.

Answer (score 2):

Is your formatter name="PATTERN" is configured in `/opt/eap/standalone/configuration/logging.properties`

Here is a configuration that works for me :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN" />
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>
  <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN" />
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log" />
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <append value="true" />
  </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
  <async-handler name="ASYNC">
    <queue-length value="512" />
    <overflow-action value="block" />
    <subhandlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE" />
    </subhandlers>
  </async-handler>
  <logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN" />
  </logger>
  <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
    <level name="WARN" />
  </logger>
  <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG" />
  </logger>
  <logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN" />
  </logger>
  <logger category="jacorb">
    <level name="WARN" />
  </logger>
  <logger category="jacorb.config">
    <level name="ERROR" />
  </logger>
  <root-logger>
    <level name="INFO" />
    <handlers>
      <handler name="ASYNC" />
      <handler name="FILE" />
    </handlers>
  </root-logger>
  <formatter name="OPENSHIFT">
    <custom-formatter module="org.jboss.logmanager.ext" class="org.jboss.logmanager.ext.formatters.LogstashFormatter">
      <properties>
        <property name="metaData" value="log-handler=CONSOLE" />
      </properties>
    </custom-formatter>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n" />
  </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

and the `logging.properties` :

```
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```